# How to get require() error message?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, solidity-0.5.x, revert-opcode, receipts

I can see the error message on Etherscan.

But I can't find it in `getTransactionRecept()`.

Is there any special settings that I need set in my Genesis.json before I can see it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! I made an NPM package to help with this: [eth-revert-reason](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-revert-reason). You can use that package to get the revert reason from a transaction with just the hash!

---

It is hard to decode the revert reason in a generalized manner. Many different factors, such as web3.js vs. ethers, Geth vs. Parity, etc. will result in different results for all the answers posted here. Some issues are:

1. For a Kovan transaction, you need a custom provider that exposes Parity `trace` methods.
2. Transactions may result in different messages depending on the context of the block they are called from. Because of this, you may need to be running a full-archival node in order to retrieve the correct error message.

In a happy-path case, the code to retrieve the revert reason is:

```
const provider = customProvider || ethers.getDefaultProvider(network)
const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash)
const code = await provider.call(tx)
```

While the code to generate the revert reason in the normal case is simple, the non-happy-path cases are surprisingly difficult to handle, however this package attempts to appease this.

Comment: So your package would return the same revert-message on a given transaction, regardless of which node (Geth, Parity, Ganache for local networks) or facade (infura, alchemy, etherscan) is used in order to interact with the network?

Comment: In it's current form, no. However, it is on the roadmap. https://github.com/authereum/eth-revert-reason#future-work